# jquery post call and reloading after every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing the ajax functionality where what i want is, after every successful ajax call, the div should get refreshed.

Currently i am considering of using setTimeout but not sure how to proced ahead

Here is my curret code

```
$(document).on('click','.openbrand',function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var name = $(this).attr('data-rel');
        var data = 'name='+name+'&id='+id;
        $.post("update.cfm",{id:id,brand:name},function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

        });
    });

 <div class="reloadcounters" style="float:right; padding:10px; position:absolute;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">#fans#</a> <i style="cursor:pointer;" data-rel="#brand#" data-id="#id#" class="fa fa-heart-o openbrand"></i></div>
```

i want to refresh the `reloadcounters` after the result set

Answer (score 0):

```
function refresh(){
    $.post("update.cfm",{id:id,brand:name},function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
       setTimeout(function(){refresh();}, 5000);
    });
}


$(document).on('click','.openbrand',function(e) {
        id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        name = $(this).attr('data-rel');
        data = 'name='+name+'&id='+id;
        refresh();
        document.unbind("click"); //Optional, do not know if needed
    });
```

Comment: I don't think the question title actually meant "every 5 seconds" :) I read the question as "5 seconds after every click".

Comment: But is what I understand when I read "after every 5 seconds" xD

Comment: We will see, but I think that was simply bad grammar :)

Comment: i think my question is not read properly, i want the div having id as: `reloadcounters` to reload after evry update or say 5 seconds, the code you gave me actualy updating the action page, which is never gonna be visible on screen

Comment: The code is not expected to work as is, before setTimeout, inside refresh function, you should put the code that actually refresh the content, that I don´t know how should look, but thought that somehow it came along with the callback function, isn´t it?